# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-functions

I create azure function solution and used `func init --docker-only` to add Dockerfile . But when I try to create an image I get the following error: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile
Here is an image of my Solution and Dockerfile Structure:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the right folder? You should run `docker build ...` command from folder with `Dockerfile` or provide a path to it in `docker build` command.

Comment: for any reason the command was not executed in the right folder. This fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: @ExplodingKitten you should post that as answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are in the right folder? You should run `docker build ...` command from folder with `Dockerfile` or provide a path to it in `docker build` command.